# How to get a list of all users having contributed to the current page shown on page?

Tags: mediawiki

Is there syntax in MediaWiki based Wikis to show the list of all users having contributed to the (current) page?

Just a flat list of unique users (clickable, ideally), NOT a link to the pages's full History page.

Answer (score 1):

If you can install extensions, [the contributors extension](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:Contributors) will allow that.

You could also get the data via the API. Media Wiki documents it [here](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Contributors).

In Wikipedia the [following URL](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&prop=contributors&titles=Aliso_Creek_(Orange_County)&format=json) will get the contributors to the Aliso Creek (Orange County) page. 
`https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&prop=contributors&titles=Aliso_Creek_(Orange_County)&format=json`

Comment: I see.. I was hoping for something to put on a page, not an API call. Probably doesn't exist then? Unless there is some way to call an API from within page and format and insert the result into the page? I'm probably dreaming..)

Comment: I believe the OP is looking for a template that can be added to the page itself. Something like `{{contributors}}` that could be included in the MediaWiki markup.

Comment: Sorry about that. You could write your own plugin using the API response . . . but it looks like one exists already.  I updated the response.